# Tapping on Ubuntu Dock on a touch screen opens two instances of a program

Tags: touchscreen, ubuntu-dock

Tapping on Ubuntu Dock on a touch screen opens two instances of a program.

For example, if I tap on the Gedit in my ubuntu Dock, two Gedit windows open.  If I tap on Nautilus, two Nautilus windows open.

I experience this issue running Ubuntu 17.10, 18.04, or 18.10 on an HP Spectre x360 Convertible 15-bl1XX.

Is anyone else experiencing this, and if so is there a way to fix this?

* This issue also affects 18.04 and 18.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround for Dash-to-Dock...

1. Save the following patch as `~/Downloads/appIcons.js.patch`

   ```
   @@ -357,6 +367,9 @@ var MyAppIcon = new Lang.Class({
            let modifiers = event ? event.get_state() : 0;
            let focusedApp = tracker.focus_app;

   +        if (event.type() == Clutter.EventType.TOUCH_END && event.is_pointer_emulated())
   +            return;
   +
            // Only consider SHIFT and CONTROL as modifiers (exclude SUPER, CAPS-LOCK, etc.)
            modifiers = modifiers & (Clutter.ModifierType.SHIFT_MASK | Clutter.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK);
   ```
2. Apply the patch

   ```
   cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
   sudo cp appIcons.js appIcons.js.original
   sudo patch appIcons.js ~/Downloads/appIcons.js.patch
   ```

   If Dash-to-Dock is installed locally, replace `/usr/share/gnome-shell` above with `~/.local/share/gnome-shell`.
3. Verify the patch

   ```
   diff appIcons.js appIcons.js.original
   ```

Reference: https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/128#issuecomment-432913072